# Customise alert view with multiple buttons

Tags: swift, uibutton, closures, swift4

I am designing a customised generic alert view which is shown below:

**Alert view Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

However the 2 buttons in this view always perform same action.

**It always perform the second line of code below for both buttons.**

```
optionAlertVC.btn_ok.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: ok)
optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: cancel)
```

**Show some code for helping me to resolve this issue.**

**ViewController:**

```
func logout() {
    AlertManager.shared.showAlertWithTwoOptions(viewController: self, message: "Confirm to logout?", okTitle: "Log out", dismissTitle: "Cancel", ok: {
        self.gotoLogin()
    }, cancel: {
        //nothing to do
    }, title: "Logout")
}
```

**AlertManager:**

```
typealias ok = () -> Void
typealias cancel = () -> Void
func showAlertWithTwoOptions(viewController: UIViewController, message: String, okTitle: String, dismissTitle:String, ok: @escaping ok , cancel: @escaping cancel, title:String? = nil) {
    guard let optionAlertVC = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AlertView", owner: nil, options: nil)?[1] as? OptionAlertVC else {
        print("error in loading error alert")
        return
    }
    optionAlertVC.lbl_title.text = title ?? "Warning"
    optionAlertVC.lbl_message.text = message
    optionAlertVC.iv_icon.image = UIImage(named: "icon_warning")
    optionAlertVC.btn_ok.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyTheme.greenSuccess
    optionAlertVC.btn_ok.setTitle(okTitle, for: .normal)
    optionAlertVC.btn_ok.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyTheme.redWarning
    optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.setTitle(dismissTitle, for: .normal)
    optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1

    optionAlertVC.btn_ok.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: ok)
    optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: cancel)

    viewController.present(optionAlertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**UIButtonExtension:**

```
extension UIButton {
    fileprivate func actionHandleBlock(action:(() -> Void)? = nil) {
        struct __ {
            static var action :(() -> Void)?
        }
        if action != nil {
            __.action = action
        } else {
            __.action?()
        }
    }

    @objc private func triggerActionHandleBlock() {
        self.actionHandleBlock()
    }

    func actionHandle(controlEvents control :UIControl.Event, ForAction action:@escaping () -> Void) {
        self.actionHandleBlock(action: action)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UIButton.triggerActionHandleBlock), for: control)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not handle `button` touches in this way. Secondly, you named the `struct` badly. If i have to say something about that `struct` then how should i name it so that you will know i am talking about that `struct`?

Coming to the actual issue, it becomes tricky sometime when you handle something with `static`. As you declared a `static` var `action` (i.e, `static var action :(() -> Void)?` ) on `struct ___`, no matter how many buttons you have, it will always call the latest button callback(i.e, a `closure`) because its not an `array` that can keep callback actions for all the buttons, its just one variable so it will keep on overwriting the previous `button` callback with the latest one. I believe you should remove this extension implementation of `UIButton` as it will keep on causing unwanted issues.

You actually don't need to do anything extra to handle a `UIButton` touch. Just declare separate method for each button and tell the button about that method while adding a target as below,

```
class OptionAlertVC: UIViewController {

    var btn_ok: UIButton!
    var btn_cancel: UIButton!

    public var okCallback: (() -> Void)?
    public var cancelCallback: (() -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btn_ok.addTarget(self, action: #selector(okAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn_cancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func okAction() {
        okCallback?()
    }

    @objc func cancelAction() {
        cancelCallback?()
    }
}
```

Now, in `showAlertWithTwoOptions`, you can remove the below lines,

```
optionAlertVC.btn_ok.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: ok)
optionAlertVC.btn_cancel.actionHandle(controlEvents: .touchUpInside, ForAction: cancel)
```

Instead, set the callbacks as this,

```
optionAlertVC.okCallback = ok
optionAlertVC.cancelCallback = cancel
```